# Is there an equivalent bsxfun in TensorFlow as there in Matlab?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was trying to translate the following MATLAB code to tensorflow:

```
WW = sum(W.^2, 1); % ( 1 x D^(l)= sum( (D^(l-1) x D^(l)), 1 )
XX = sum(A.^2, 2); % (M x 1) = sum( (M x D^(l-1)), 2 )
bsxfun(@plus, WW, XX) ; % (M x D^(l)) - (M x D^(l)) = (M x D^(l-1)) * (D^(l-1) x D^(l)) - (M x D^(l))
```

which is very simple MATLAB code and was wondering if there was an equivalent code in TensorFlow. Ideally, `W` and/or `X` should be `tf.Variable(init)` variables because I'd like to compute the derivatives with respect to each variable.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow, like NumPy, does broadcasting.

You can do

```
WW + XX
```

and it'll figure out the sizes itself

See the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: I see, so `W.^2` is just `W*W` in numpy (and then some equivalent sum operation). The question I still have is, if I do all this in numpy it doesn't necessarily mean that  TensorFlow would take derivatives correctly of this and do backprop correctly.

Comment: basically it seems is there is any `tf.MATH_OP`  then the derivatives and backprop will be computed correctly. Though Im yet to find official documentation confirming this.